# \sc not printed

Tags: fonts, printing, acrobat

I'm using the `\sc` command as `{\sc Tight}` but I can't see (on the monitor and when printed) it in acrobat reader but only with okular. Do you know why?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. You shouldn't use the old LaTeX2.09 macros like `\sc`, `\it` etc. but `\textsc{<text>}` instead. I might be caused by your font. Which one are you using? Adding a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem would help.

Answer (score 7):

As Martin said in the comments, you shouldn't really use `\sc` any more. Use one of `\textsc{foo}` or `{\scshape foo}`. If this doesn't work, perhaps you need to specify a font encoding to make it work. If you're using a non-standard font, it might be that you need to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or the like to your preamble.

Without some more information on what font you're using, whether you're using LaTeX, XeTeX or what have you, we can't really help you further.

Comment: I'm using `pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.4)`. I'm producing dvi and next I convert it with dvipdf. I tried to change `\sc` to `\textsc`, and adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but nothing changed. I also tried with `pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)`: same result. If I use directly pdflatex it works

Comment: @wiso then I suggest you use `pdflatex`? Is there any reason you specifically want to use those other engines?

Comment: @Seamus: I'd like to use pdflatex, but I can't, my collaborations is made by 1000+ people and I can't change it by myself.

Comment: @wiso please update your question with information about what exactly you are trying to compile: a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be useful. Also think about including the `.log` file.

Comment: sorry, I'm not able to reproduce a minimal example. I tried to create it, but it works. So I tried to start from the problematic tex, and to remove code until the problem disappear. The problem is that sometimes if I remove a sentence without nothing in particular the problem disappears! And this happens with different sentences. So I tried to open the full document on another computer and everythings was ok.

Comment: @wiso that is the sort of thing you should think of doing _before_ asking a question here.